# JScrollPane collapses after resizing JFrame

Tags: java, jtable, jframe, jscrollpane, layout-manager

I'm having trouble with some `LayoutManager` issues (I believe). I'm working on a little project for my own, and i have replicated my problem below. The problem is that when I make the window  even a pixel smaller (in x or y direction, doesn't matter) than the original size the whole `JScrollPane` collapses, to the point that the table it is no longer visible.

I Want the `JPanel` to re-size according to the `JFrame`, without the `JScrollPane` collapsing. I've added color to the borders to illustrate the problem.

I have looked up all sorts of questions to solve this issue, but the answers vary a lot and I have found no suitable solution for my problem. I have a general understanding of LayoutManagers but clearly not extensive enough to figure this one out. Thank you for any help in advance.

Frame normal:

[image: Frame normal]

Frame smaller (Collapsed / Disappeared table):

[image: Frame smaller]

Frame larger (No problems):

[image: Frame larger]

Code (SSCCE):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;


public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private JPanel EmployeePanel;
    private JButton add, remove, edit;
    private JTable EmployeeTable;
    private JScrollPane EmployeeTableScrollPane;

    private JMenuBar menu;
    private JMenu file;
    private JMenuItem exit;

    private String[] columns = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"};
    private String[][] data = {
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"}
            };



    public MainWindow(){
        //Set title
        super("Scheduler");

        //Set LaF
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException
                | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Set JFrame properties
        this.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,300));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Initialize JComponents
        EmployeeTable = new JTable(data, columns){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        EmployeeTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(EmployeeTable);

        add = new JButton("Add");
        remove = new JButton("Remove");
        edit = new JButton("Edit");

        menu = new JMenuBar();
        file = new JMenu("File");
        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        //Set MenuBar
        file.add(exit);
        menu.add(file);
        this.setJMenuBar(menu);

        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            //Don't mind the method i use for now to close the application
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            }

        });

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        EmployeePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        //Add JScrollPane
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 3;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.anchor = constraints.NORTH;
        constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
        EmployeePanel.add(EmployeeTableScrollPane, constraints);

        //Add Buttons
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.anchor = constraints.SOUTH;
        constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
        EmployeePanel.add(add, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.anchor = constraints.SOUTH;
        constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
        EmployeePanel.add(edit, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 2;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.anchor = constraints.SOUTH;
        constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
        EmployeePanel.add(remove, constraints);

        //Add EmployeePanel
        this.add(EmployeePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        EmployeeTableScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW));
        EmployeeTable.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));

        this.validate();
        this.pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MainWindow();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the scroll pane, change

```
constraints.fill = constraints.HORIZONTAL;
```

to

```
constraints.fill = constraints.BOTH;
```

The second issue mentioned in the comment is fixed
by adding

```
constraints.weighty = 0;
```

to the buttons.

Complete fixed example:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private JPanel EmployeePanel;
    private JButton add, remove, edit;
    private JTable EmployeeTable;
    private JScrollPane EmployeeTableScrollPane;

    private JMenuBar menu;
    private JMenu file;
    private JMenuItem exit;

    private final String[] columns = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"};
    private String[][] data = {
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"},
            {"First Name", "Last Name", "Initials"}
            };



    public MainWindow(){
        //Set title
        super("Scheduler");

        initUI();

    }

    private void initUI() {

        createMenuBar();

        //Set JFrame properties
        //setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        //setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,300));

        //setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Initialize JComponents
        EmployeeTable = new JTable(data, columns){
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        EmployeeTableScrollPane = new JScrollPane(EmployeeTable);

        add = new JButton("Add");
        remove = new JButton("Remove");
        edit = new JButton("Edit");


        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        EmployeePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        //Add JScrollPane
        constraints.weightx = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 1;
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 3;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        EmployeePanel.add(EmployeeTableScrollPane, constraints);

        //Add Buttons
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.weighty = 0;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        EmployeePanel.add(add, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        EmployeePanel.add(edit, constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 2;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        constraints.gridwidth = 1;
        constraints.gridheight = 1;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        EmployeePanel.add(remove, constraints);

        //Add EmployeePanel
        this.add(EmployeePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        EmployeeTableScrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.YELLOW));
        EmployeeTable.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));

        //this.validate();
        pack();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void createMenuBar() {

        menu = new JMenuBar();
        file = new JMenu("File");
        exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

        //Set MenuBar
        file.add(exit);
        menu.add(file);
        setJMenuBar(menu);        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainWindow ex = new MainWindow();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Issues fixed:

No need to call `this.validate();`

You called both

```
setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
```

and

```
pack();
```

Yout either call one or the other, the `pack()` is the preferred way.

No need to call

```
setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

The `BorderLayout` is the default layout of the frame's content pane.

The application should be started on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread):

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        MigLayoutMainWindow ex = new MigLayoutMainWindow();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Finally, I would go with `MigLayout` or `GroupLayout` managers instead
of the `GridBagLayout` manager. They are more powerful and flexible.

Comment: Ok a big "Doh!" on my part. But now the table takes up only half of the screen when i scale down. Classic case of overlooking obvious problems when you are staring at your code too long.

Comment: I will update the answer in a minute; there are several issues.

Comment: Wow, i didn't know `weighty = 0` will keep the default button-size intact. The answer was very simple after all. Thank you very much, learned a bunch. I just have one question: `pack` doesn't allow you to manipulate your applications size, why should i use it over `setSize`?

Comment: The `pack()` sizes its children according to their preferred size. So you indirectly influence the size of your components by defining their preferred size. In your example, putting data in the table influences sets the preferred size of the table.

The `setSize()` is platform dependent. One should generally avoid setting any pixel sizes in the layout. The size might be OK one one platform, but it will be incorrect on another.

Comment: So `setPrefferedSize` is ok to use, in addition to `pack`?

Comment: Generally, one should let the component define its preferred size. For instance, the `JButton` calculates its size based on its text or icon. When the font of the application changes (or the text is translated), so does the preferred size of the button. Image that we would have to change preferred sizes dynamically in such cases...

But there are some legitimate cases, for instance we need a panel that will display some color. The initial preferred size of a panel is very tiny and therefore, we set its preferred size to a custom value.

Answer (score 1):

use a `BorderLayout` around the elements.

Also make sure you are setting the 'preferred size' property on your scrollpane's. I've had strange behavior (panes/fields collapsing/disappearing) when frames and panels get resized when this property is not set.

Comment: Do you mean within the `EmployeePanel`? Because i am using a `BorderLayout` within the `JFrame`. And about the PreferredSize, I've read multiple post saying that using any sizing method (`setXXSize`) should be avoided when using LayoutManagers.

Comment: try constraints.BOTH if that doesnt work apply border layout within the EmployeePanel.@Alexander

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i'll have to accept Jan Bodnar's awnser for his extensive help.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar with a scroll pane and a way i found to get it working is to calculate the height manually and then override the height attribute. i took this approach as I want part of what i was building to stay the same height regardless of how the window is resized. Scroll panes are funny things to size.